# Linux thread id comparison

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

So, I'm having a very bad time finding a current thread id in a list of structures, which reflect information about threads.

Basically, each element from the list has a field `pthread_t id`. My search function is something like:

```
int thread_pos(pthread_t tid)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < my_threads.thread_num; i++)
    {   
        printf("for: %d %d %d\n", my_threads.vector[i].id, tid, pthread_equal(my_threads.vector[i].id, tid));
        if (pthread_equal(my_threads.vector[i].id, tid))
        {   
            printf("found\n");
            return i;
        }   
    }   

    return -1; 
}
```

As there is only 1 element in my_threads.vector, it prints one line:

```
419817216 419817216 0
```

Data structures:

```
struct my_thread_t
{
    pthread_t id;
};

struct my_threads_t
{
    struct my_thread_t vector[100];
    int thread_num;
};
```

I add elements to list this way:

```
pthread_create(&new_tid, NULL, start_thread, &my_threads.vector[my_threads.thread_num].thread_arg);

my_threads.vector[my_threads.thread_num].id = new_tid;
my_threads.thread_num++;
```

The problem is, though the element is there, in the list, it fails to find it. I printed a line on each comparison (for example `419817216 419817216 0`, showing the tid in list, the key tid, and the result of pthread_equal). As you can see, the numerical representation is the same, but somehow pthread_equal says they aren't.

What I'm missing?

Comment: That *should* work, however, seeing how it doesn't, obviously you're missing something. And without seeing the **actual** code, it's really hard to know what that something is.

Comment: @NikBougalis, yes, that is what makes me desperate. I can't find elsewhere the bug. Maybe someone could give me some hints on tid comparison...

Comment: Uhm, how can we give hints with the information you gave us, beyond saying "well, your pseudocode looks right." Why not simply **post** the **actual** code and let us see if we can see something wrong with **that**?

Comment: @NikBougalis, added more snippets of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add / remove / check elements to `my_threads` from different threads everything could get wild.
From your fragment of code I suspect you don't have [mutex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) protection for this structure.

If you really did not implement locking and need to read list more often than write, consider about [pthread_rwlock()](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/pthread_rwlock.3.html) interface.

UPDATE: Also could you please check `sizeof(pthread_t)` on your platform? If 8 (unsigned long), you should at least use %lu format `in` printf.

Comment: No, I don't. I only have 2 threads, first writes the tid in the list, second does the search. However, I synchronized them using a sleep, same thing happened. Funny thing, it found the tid in the list, if I used (int) casts, instead of pthread_equal(), so I suspect there is something I don't know about pthread_equal or pthread_t type.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky `sleep` doesn't synchronize anything, and synchronization *may* be an issue. Short of what Roman said, and the fact that you don't seem to check the return value of the `pthread_create` call, I don't see anything wrong with the code that does the lookup in the array.

Comment: @NikBougalis, `sleep` make sure one thread will start do some work after other almost finishes (stuck in join, waiting). How can you explain that (int) tid_1 == (int) tid_2, and nonetheless pthread_equal returns 0? Sizeof(pthread_t) returned 8 (same as unsigned long).

Comment: No, `sleep` doesn't make sure of that . If you want one thread to wait for another then use `pthread_join`.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky Please change output format from %d to %lu in your pthread_t printf(). This could explain everything.

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko, YES! There was somewhere a cast to int, then an assigned to pthread_t, and therefore loss of precision. Fixed it!

Comment: Bingo! I spent lot of time 10 years ago on these pthreads :-) - was nice time. Honest bounty hunt and entertainment - my time they were 4 bytes. Actually this is the reason pthread_equal is recommended.